# Neo4j - Get all related nodes of type and create new relationship

Tags: neo4j, relationship, graph-theory, graph-databases

I have a dataset that looks like this (Artefact)-[HAS]-(Keyword), keywords can be shared multiple times by artefacts. What I am trying to achieve is;

Returning most interconnected keyword nodes, count of artefacts related to keywords, count of the overlap between keyword nodes and the hop to another keyword (keyword)-(artefact)-(keywords), the "shared" artefact count between two keywords.

In other words a count of the artefact records within an intersect between two keyword nodes. For example given these three artefact nodes

1) **spoon** (keywords; **metal**, food)

2) **sword** (keywords; **metal**, fighting)

3) **fork** (keywords; **metal**, food)

The query would therefore return the keyword node, count of artefacts related to keyword (3, spoon, sword and fork), count of the keywords related by artefact between keyword nodes (metal has 2 indirect connections to food and 1 to fighting).

Once I've worked that out, for the sake of speed because I realise this is a big query, create a related_to relationship between keywords with the count of the number of artefacts they share in common. Only select 1 record to create this relationship, to test it works :) (hence limit 1)

```
MATCH (n:Keyword)-[r*2]-(x:Keyword)
WITH n, COUNT(r) AS c, x
LIMIT 1
MERGE (n)-[s:RELATED_KEY]-(x) SET s.weight = c
```

I'm using neo4j community edition (2.1.6),

Many thanks, Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return you the first part of your answer :

```
MATCH (k:Keyword)
WITH k
LIMIT 1
MATCH (k)<-[:HAS]-(a)
WITH k, collect(a) as artefacts
WITH k, artefacts, size(artefacts) as c
UNWIND artefacts as artefact
MATCH (k)<-[:HAS]-(artefact)-[:HAS]->(k2)
RETURN c, artefacts, collect(distinct(k2.name)) as keywords, count(distinct(k2.name)) as keyWordsCount
```

[image]

However, I guess you may create the relationships between the related nodes directly :

```
MATCH (k:Keyword)
WITH k
LIMIT 1
MATCH (k)<-[:HAS]-(a)-[:HAS]->(other)
MERGE (k)-[r:RELATED_TO]->(other)
ON CREATE SET r.weight = 1
ON MATCH SET r.weight = r.weight + 1
```